# how to unit test a function accessing context with Robolectrics

Tags: android, robolectric

I have a simple function which returns my app's version name:

```
public static String myVersionName(Context context) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
        return context.getPackageManager()
                      .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    }
```

I have `Robolectrics` in project. I am wondering how to **unit test** the above function with Robolectrics? Is this function testable with Robolectrics?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **assertEquals()** from **JUnit** after passing the proper context